# How to replace/fix a messed up /bin/sh and /bin/dash

Tags: 11.10, server, command-line, bash, dash-shell

I have corrupted my /bin/sh and have no idea how to replace it. I accidentally copied over it. How can I fix this?

I am running Ubuntu Server 11.10, no X.

update: I have tried the fix that was kindly offered by Eliah but i think i copied over /bin/dash too!

update: OUTPUT OF `cd /bin; file sh dash bash; md5sum sh dash bash`

```
sh:   symbolic link to `dash'
dash: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x5d23ca7cbab4993f295d1089b4860eb32d406fab, stripped
bash: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xf199a4a89ac968c2e0e99f2410600b9d7e995187, stripped
c229085928dc19e8d9bd29fe88268504  sh
c229085928dc19e8d9bd29fe88268504  dash
089ed56cd74e63f461bef0fdfc2d159a  bash
```

Answer (score 4):

In all remotely recent versions of Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is just a symbolic link to `/bin/dash`. So make sure that whatever is currently called `/bin/sh` is backed up somewhere if it's important, then delete it and make a new link.

To remove whatever is currently `/bin/sh` and restore `/bin/sh` to what it's supposed to be, run these commands:

```
cd /bin
sudo rm sh
sudo ln -s dash sh
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for replying so fast. I ran the commands you mentioned and logged out and back in and now I am seeing this "-bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory". Is this right?

Comment: I fear i coped over /bin/dash.

Comment: @Joel What's the output of `cd /bin; file sh dash bash; md5sum sh dash bash`? (You can add this to your question and just comment here so I'm notified; that way it can be formatted in a way that makes clear where one line ends and where the next begins.)

Comment: i am struggling to get him to boot now, stand by, it looks like a partition table is missing...

Comment: Ok take a look at the output Eliah...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you still have bash, use bash as sh.

```
sudo ln -s bash /bin/sh
```

Then reinstall dash

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dash
```

Comment: I ran it and got this..."E: Sub-process /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true returned an error code (100)
E: Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true" @eliah-kagan

Comment: @Joel Then it sounds like there's more broken stuff than just dash. What did you do to break it exactly?

Comment: The only exact thing I know I did wrong was accidentally wrote over the /bin/sh with a plain txt doc. I was however, in the process of re-configuring postfix when I fist saw this breakdown. The server stopped sending mail and thats why i was checking the config. I try to be very careful but obviously have done something bad. I just tried to reboot (Have been on SSH) and its not coming up, so i'm walking over to pull the server out of the server room now... What do you suggest I do?

Comment: @Joel From your description, it seems you edited `/bin/dash` through the `/bin/sh` symlink (which would be the usual behavior of a text editor), rather than overwriting the `/bin/sh` symlink with a real file. You're right that this would overwrite `/bin/dash`. This answer, as written, won't always work, but the idea is just right for your situation. Try `cd /bin`, then `sudo rm sh`, then `sudo ln -s bash sh`, then `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dash`. If that doesn't work, please add the console text to your question (you can use `script` to record it).